# React-Native Device: (1:0) Error loading dependency: Error: Failed to install module 'rea': Attempted to import missing module 'fs'

Tags: react-native, expo

I was building a component that contains a ScrollView and I came across an issue, I was using the map function to go over all nodes in array and show the values in the scrollview: I always got this error

"Device: (1:0) Error loading dependency: Error: Failed to install module 'ex': Attempted to import missing module 'fs'" some times the 'ex' is interchanged with 'rea'

my code in the render of the App.js is:

```
render() {
   return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
       <Button title="toggle contacts" onPress={this.toggleContacts} />
       <ScrollView >
          <View>
          {contacts.map(contact => (
              <View key={contact.key}>    
              <Text>{contact.name}</Text>
              <Text>{contact.phone}</Text>
              </View>
              ))}
          </View> 
       </ScrollView>
     </View>
     )
 }
}
```

My solutions all failed, as I am loading he contacts from a helper file that generates a random name and phone from a big list of data (list of values reduced for this post clarity).

the helper file looks like this:

```
const NUM_CONTACTS = 100

const firstNames = ["Alex", "Ali", "Joy", "Lisa", "Susu", "Mark", "Bob", "James"]

const lastNames = ["Jones", "Smith", "Blow", "Big", "Small", "Sundance", "Hero", "Newold"]


// generate a random number between min and max

const rand = (max, min = 0) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1 )) + min

// genrate name
const generateName = () => `${firstNames[rand(firstNames.length - 1)]} ${lastNames[rand(lastNames.length - 1)]}`

// generate a phone number
const generatePhonenumber = () => `${rand(999,100)}-${rand(999,100)}-${rand(9999,1000)}`

// create a person 
const createContact = () => ({name: generateName(), phone: generatePhonenumber()})

export const compareNames = (contact1, contact2) => contact1.name > contact2.name

// add keys to based on index
const addKeysToContacts = (contact, key) =>({
  key: key,
  ...contact,
}) 

const addKeys = (val, key) => ({key, ...val})

//create an array of length NUM_CONTACTS AND ordered in alphabetical order
export default Array.from({length: NUM_CONTACTS}, createContact).map(addKeys)
```

Comment: Have you tried simplifying your app to close to the bare minimum (ex: reduce dependencies only to the basics) in another project to help identify the root cause?

Comment: I will try to hard code the contacts to a list of 10 contacts and see how it goes...

Comment: @AhmadAl-Baqawi did you solve that? .. it happened with me and when I refreshed the page, it went off!

Comment: yes I had to upgrade the react package and all was fixed. I am running RN package version 53.0.0